# Key Error when deploying Flask App to heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, google-api

I deployed my App to Heroku and it is showing me a 'keyError' regarding 'items'. My code runs perfectly fine locally but won't on Heroku. Does someone know how I can fix that?
Thank you very much!

My Code:

```
def getbooktitle():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files['image']
        img = Image.open(file.stream)
        booktitle = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

        api_key = "myapikey"
        url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={booktitle}&key={api_key}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_response = response.json()
        volume_info = json_response['items'][0]['volumeInfo']
        title = volume_info.get('title')
        author = volume_info.get('authors')
        imageslink = volume_info['imageLinks']
        smallimage = imageslink['smallThumbnail']
        return jsonify({"books": [{'title': title, 'author': author[0], 'imageLink': smallimage}]})
```

View logs:

```
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826905+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-20 15:50:16,823] ERROR in app: Exception on /getbook [POST]
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826914+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826915+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826915+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826917+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826917+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826918+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826918+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826919+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826919+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826920+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 21, in getbooktitle
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826921+00:00 app[web.1]:     volume_info = json_response["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]
2021-07-20T15:50:16.826922+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 'items'
```

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with Flask or Heroku, it's a more general web development or programming question. The clue is in the error message — there is no key "items" in the `json_response` dictionary. The reason is likely because the book title isn't found or is invalid, or your API key is wrong.

Comment: @KarlSutt Thank you Karl! The API Key I'm using is the same one I'm using, when I'm testing the App locally and then it works perfectly fine. I double checked on the google cloud platform, but it's the same and it's not restricted. I also tried the link with a book name and my API key and it shows me 'items'.

Comment: You could print out the response before accessing the keys to see what's there and if there are any other clues that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using config variables in Heroku?

If you are, make sure there are no **hyphens** in your config variables. I had the same issue.. app was running perfectly fine locally, but on Heroku it would bring back a KeyError. I was stumped for hours. Once I changed the hyphens to underscores, it worked perfecty fine.